# js validation never fails?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple form where user specifies a name and problem is that this:

> website_name==="" || !/^[a-z]*$/

Is never true, when I enter a number it never makes background red, why?

```
   $( "#website_name" ).keyup(function() {
        var message;
      if(website_name==="" || !/^[a-z]*$/)
      {
        $("#website_name").css('border', '3px solid red', 'background', '#f27676');
        message = 'Only lower case characters allowed!';
        $('div.modal-body').append(message);
      }else{
        $("#website_name").css('border', '3px solid green', 'background', '#56c145');
        message = 'Your name is correct';
        $('div.modal-body').append(message);
      }
    });
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `.test()` the value:

```
!/^[a-z]*$/.test(this.value)
```

```js
console.log(!/^[a-z]*$/.test('123'));
```

Comment: how about to only append the message once and just change it when validation fails/passes? because atm everytime it fails it get appended

Comment: `$('div.modal-body').empty().append(message);` or `$('div.modal-body').text(message);`

Comment: @Przemek   use `.html()` instead of `.append()`.More accurate

Comment: @AlivetoDie Is there any issue with `.empty().append()`? _More accurate_ does not make sense.

Comment: why to use two function when one can correctly do it?that's i mean

Comment: the problem is if I use $('div.modal-body').empty().append(message); or $('div.modal-body').text(message);, it get rid of the input field and I want it to stay there

Comment: Okay! what you can do is place another element in the modal body and place the content init. if you have access to change it. `$('div.modal-body .msgPlaceholder').empty().append(message);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to test the regex against your website_name variable.

```
$("#website_name").keyup(function () {
    var message;
    var pattern = new RegExp("^[a-z]*$");
    if (website_name === "" || pattern.test(website_name) === false) {
        $("#website_name").css('border', '3px solid red', 'background', '#f27676');
        message = 'Only lower case characters allowed!';
        $('div.modal-body').append(message);
    } else {
        $("#website_name").css('border', '3px solid green', 'background', '#56c145');
        message = 'Your name is correct';
        $('div.modal-body').append(message);
    }
});
```